# how to set up mysql database using homebrew

Tags: mysql, macos

I want to set up a local mysql database on MacOS.

I've used:

```
brew install mysql
```

As a means of installing the software.

Tried

```
mysql -u root
```

But this returns

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

You would expect this since I didn't have a password to offer initially.

After digging around I found this code as a means of getting mysql running without password.

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --user=root
```

The response sounds promising, I thought:

```
2023-01-08T07:40:02.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Davids-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
2023-01-08T07:40:02.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
2023-01-08T07:40:03.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Davids-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
```

But when I tried

```
mysql -u root
```

I received

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Then tried

```
    mysql -u root -p

Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How can I set up a password for mysql database if I can't actually have initial access?

Confused.

UPDATE: Then I've looked at this link https://database.guide/install-mysql-on-a-mac/

It suggested running

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

But foiled again

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Does `sudo mysql` get you in?  Once in, you can create yourself a normal user.

Comment: No, same situation: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: It is described in the docs: [How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it won't allow you without starting mysql in safe mode.
Please follow the below steps.

Stop the MySQL server if it is running:

```
brew services stop mysql
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

This will start the MySQL server without loading the grant tables, which store the user privileges. This allows you to connect to the MySQL server as the root user without a password.

```
mysql -u root

USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('<<**Custom_Password**>>') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

Stop the MySQL server:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

Start the MySQL server normally:

```
brew services start mysql
```

You should now be able to connect to the MySQL server as the root user using the new password.